# Python: Is a function defined in the main thread and called from another run from the main thread or calling thread

Tags: python, multithreading, function, pygame

Let's say I have a program as such:

```
import threading

def dosomething():
    print "Something"

class thread2(threading.Thread):
    def run():
        dosomething()

thread2().start()
```

would `dosomething()` run from the main thread, where it was defined, or `thread2`, where it was called?

I'm using this for a `pygame` program, since you can't call pygame's methods from multiple classes.

Comment: @JoseP OK Thanks, but you might want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you declared the function. The function is going to be executed by the thread that calls it.